# Can Google show a simple list of URLs visited?

Tags: google, google-analytics, url, logging

Is there a way for Google Analytics (v4) to show me a simple detail log of URLs visited?

I don't want any aggregate data, just a simple HTTP log like the kind you'd get from NGINX or something like that, with the IP, browser, time, url, path, etc.

Every answer I've found says something about going to the "Behavior" tab, which is missing in Google Analytics v4.

Comment: Rather than trying to get this data out of GA, why don't you actually consult your HTTP log from your web server?

Comment: Unfortunately for this purpose, my web server is a CDN and I don't have access to their logs. @StephenOstermiller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, GA wasn't made for it. However, obviously the raw data is exactly that: just log of raw hits.

So for people who feel comfortable working with tables rather than UI (basically anyone comfortable with SQL), there's an easy option of moving the data into Big Query and querying it afterwards.

There's also Google Data Studio, but BQ is a lot more straightforward.

Finally, you can try using the GA4 Explorer and generate custom reports with the metrics and dimensions you want (where a metric would basically be just a hit), but Explorer is known for its bugs and counterintuitive interpretation of things.